# How to control youtube playback with Microsoft keyboard media buttons?

Tags: youtube, playback

Is there a way to control youtube playback with play/stop media button on a Microsoft keyboard? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You could...

... install the Intellitype software that came with the keyboard, or [download it from Microsoft](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/search.aspx?q=intellitype).  Then, customize the functions of the keys you want to remap through that software.  It allows you to create/assign/manage Macros, so you could then set the media playback buttons to specifically play/stop/pause Flash videos on Youtube.

Of course, if you'd like more Robust keymapping controls, you could skip the limited Microsoft software, and [go with Autohotkey instead](http://www.autohotkey.net/).  People have had success remapping even their laptop Fn and Eject keys with this.